# ip route add works manually but throws "Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than ..." when run via bash script

Tags: networking, bash, ip-routing, iproute2

I'm trying to run a script that should add this route to a table 11:

```
ip route add local 10.1.3.212 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.1.3.212 table 11
```

If I run this command manually, it is successful and I can see the entry in table 11 but if I run a script that does the following:

```
    if [[ ${IP_ROUTE} == local* ]]; then
        ip route add ${IP_ROUTE} table ${NEW_INTERFACE_TABLE} 2>>/home/ec2-user/script_output
    fi
```

where ${NEW_INTERFACE_TABLE} is 11 the script throws this error:

```
 Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "local 10.1.3.212 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.1.3.212 ".
```

Please help, I'm going nuts.

Comment: Can you run you script with "set -x" before the command in question and post the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when expanding `${IP_ROUTE}`, the text is interpreted as single parameter instead of a series of parameters. This should happen if the variable is quoted, which is not the case so it shouldn't do that.

Some things to check:

- Contents of `IFS` (you can run inside the script `set | grep -E '^IFS'`). You should get something like `IFS=$' \t\n'` which is a usual default value. Notice that the space character is listed as field separator (`IFS` variable contains just that).
- Are you actually using bash? Check that your shebang is `#!/bin/bash` instead of just `#!/bin/sh` if you are using it.
- How are you assigning the contents to the `IP_ROUTE` variable?

Comment: Thank you so much, this happened because I was splitting on new lines in the beginning of the script. I put back IFS=' ' and everything worked.

Comment: Glad you get it working. In these cases I usually do `OLDIFS=$IFS` then I change `IFS` to what I need and when finished, I restore its previous value: `IFS=$OLDIFS`.